# Configuring TFS SQL Server Instance connecting Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs

I am new to Team Foundation server and when I am configuring TFS for SQL Server, I am getting below error where TFS is not able to connect to the SQL Server instance where as when I connect to SQL Server it is connecting successfully. Both SQL Server and TFS are on the same server machine. Please advise

[Error while clicking on Test Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Fpx.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info, you need to  make sure the TFS service accounts(which you started the TFS Installer) have permissions on the DB server.

*Add the account in the list of logins in SQL Server side and retry*
   the previous operation.
 [image]

Moreover, if Windows Firewall is on the TFS box, switch it off during the installation and try again. After finish the installation reopen the firewall.

For more details  you could take a look at below similar issue:

- [Errors during TFS 2013 install–and how I worked past them](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/girishp/2013/11/05/errors-during-tfs-2013-installand-how-i-worked-past-them/)
- [Workaround Error TF255049: Punching a hole through Windows
  Firewall](https://elhajj.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/workaround-error-tf255049-punching-a-hole-through-windows-firewall/)